# Spring JmsTemplate - add custom Property

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

I am using the Spring API's `JmsTemplate` and `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` (version: `spring-jms-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar`) to publish messages 
 to an ActiveMQ topic as shown in the below code.

**TopicPublisher class:**

```
@Component
public class TopicPublisher {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private MessageConverter messageConverter;

    public void send() {
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setName("abcd");
        product.setPrice(10);

        jmsTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("product.topic", product);
    }
}
```

**MappingJackson2MessageConverter class:**

```
@Configuration
public class JMSTextMessageConverter {

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter mappingJackson2MessageConverter 
             = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        mappingJackson2MessageConverter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        mappingJackson2MessageConverter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return mappingJackson2MessageConverter;
    }   
}
```

Now, I want to set few custom headers to the JMS message being published to the topic.
I googled and could not find any example which does this. Can you help ?

Comment: Any reason why typeIdPropertyName = _type?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can add custom properties by using `convertAndSend`method from `JmsTemplate` by sending `MessagePostProcessor` as shown below:

```java
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("product.topic", product, new MessagePostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws JMSException {
                message.setStringProperty("my_property", "my_value");
                return message;
            }
        });
```

Alternative lambda syntax:

```java
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(
            "product.topic", product,
            message -> { message.setStringProperty("my_property", "my_value"); return message;}
    );
```

Comment: `message.clearProperties();`  Should Add this line before `setStringProperty` . Otherwise `javax.jms.MessageNotWriteableException` would be thrown

Comment: jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("product.topic", product, m -> {
            m.setStringProperty("my_property", "my_value");
            return m  });

Comment: what if I want to add ByteBuffer property, for example SQS supports Binary message attribute datatype, but I'm not sure that Spring JMS abstraction supports those?

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
@SendTo("product.topic")
public Message<Product> send() {
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setName("abcd");
    product.setPrice(10);

    return MessageBuilder
            .withPayload(product)
            .setHeader("code", 1234) // custom header name and value
            .build();
}
```

Reference: https://spring.io/blog/2014/04/30/spring-4-1-s-upcoming-jms-improvements